# exam: Making the header a stack of tables with different number of columns

Tags: tables, exam

For the header, I would like to make it consist of three rows with a different number of cells. However, I tried the following where I piled up three tables which made the final result not decent.

Therefore, I would like to:

1- optimize the header and find a better way, if possible, instead of three tables on top of each other,

2- make the color in the highlighted cell span all of it without the white margin surrounding it

3- and remove the extra vertical skip at the third row before the header rule.

**Minor comments:**

1- is it possible to make the header height predict the required extra height and set it automatically instead of trial and error?

2- Why is there a space, in the first row, to the right of the word `"right"`?

```
\documentclass[
addpoints,
]{exam}

\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx,mdframed,array,ragged2e,booktabs,fmtcount}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\RaggedLeft\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\pagestyle{headandfoot}

\extraheadheight{3cm}

\firstpageheadrule
\firstpageheader%
{}%
{%
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0em}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}L{0.33\textwidth}C{0.33\textwidth}R{0.33\textwidth}@{}}
        \toprule
        left & center & right\\
        \midrule
    \end{tabular*}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{C{\textwidth}}
        \cellcolor{gray!30}loooooooooooong text\\
        \midrule
    \end{tabular*}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{L{0.5\textwidth}R{0.5\textwidth}}
        Some looooooooooooooooong sentence. & another one
    \end{tabular*}
}%
{}

\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \question some question
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The white borders between cell-background and lines (point 2) is a known issue in conjunction with `booktabs`, you should be able to find enough information about that on the site. On minor comment 1: you could typeset the table with dummy content in a `\savebox` once and measure it. Would be stuff like `\setbox0\hbox{<your-header>}` afterwards (until `\box0` is used the next time) `\ht0` would return the height and `\dp0` the depth (total vertical size is `\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax`). Why don't you use one table and `\multicolumn`?

Comment: And the space right of "right" is added because you requested a table of a `\textwidth` but your columns don't take a full `\textwidth`, the excessive space is added on the right of the table and the rules do take the full specified width. You might want to use `tabularx` and its `X` columns instead of `tabular*` and `p`.

Comment: @Skillmon Your comments are of great help to me.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that they are useful as that was the intention of writing them :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution uses boxes instead of a tabular.  One can easily adjust the spacing to be more like a tabular using `\strut`s or increasing `\fboxsep`.

```
\documentclass[addpoints,]{exam}

\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx,mdframed,array,ragged2e,booktabs,fmtcount}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\pagestyle{headandfoot}

\newsavebox{\headbox}
\savebox{\headbox}{\def\strut{\vrule height\arraystretch\ht\strutbox
  depth\arraystretch\dp\strutbox width0pt}%
\parbox{\textwidth}{\hrule
  \strut\rlap{left}\hfill\mbox{center}\hfill\llap{right}\hrule
  \fboxsep=1pt
  \colorbox{gray!30}{\makebox[\dimexpr \textwidth-2\fboxsep][c]{\strut loooooooooooong text}}\hrule
  \strut Some looooooooooooooooong sentence.\hfill another one}}

\extraheadheight{\dimexpr \ht\headbox+\dp\headbox}

\firstpageheadrule
\firstpageheader%
{}%
{\usebox\headbox}%
{}

\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \question some question
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: I don't know whether you should use `\usebox\headbox` as I don't know whether OP wants to change the contents of that box (what if the page number or the marks should be displayed in that table?).

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I am afraid that the text inside the boxes is top-aligned. Is it possible to make it vertically centered?

Comment: It is both top and bottom aligned (descender on "g").  What you want is more space using some sort of \strut.

Comment: I am so sorry, but I don't know much to understand what you mean. What I want is to make the vertical spaces above and below, for example, the word `"Some"` the same. So, how could I achieve this?

Comment: @Diaa adding a rule of zero width but a certain height and depth would do that, e.g. `\rule[-.2ex]{0pt}{2ex}` (sizes are guessed, you might want to change the `-.2ex` and `2ex` to get proper results).

Comment: @Skillmon Sorry for the stupid question, but where should I type that? Do you mean `\hrule\rule[-.2ex]{0pt}{2ex}`?

Comment: You should do something like `\newcommand*\mystrut{\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{3.55ex}` (this time the values are tried and give reasonable results) and then us `\mystrut` just after the first `\hrule` in the first line, before "loooooooooooong" in the second and before "Some" in the third line.

Comment: I redefined \strut inside the savebox to use the same size strut as tabular uses on every line.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Many thanks for your patience. I know you are fed up with me `:)`. Just one final comment: how to control the top and bottom vertical separations at every row? For example, in the first or third row, I would like to control the top and bottom vertical skips or separations; so, how it can be done? Is this good `\hrule
\vspace{1mm}
\strut\rlap{left}\hfill\mbox{center}\hfill\llap{right}
\vspace{1mm}
\hrule`?

Comment: Or just \def\arraystretch{1.5} or so.  BTW, I have infinite patience.  At one point I taught high school math.