# exam-minipage: Using minipage inside the header

Tags: minipage, mdframed, exam

Following-up my previous questions [[1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/448759/2288),[2]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/448784/2288), I, instead, tried using `minipage` environment in order to able to freely break the lines and use the `exam` macros (e.g. `\numquestions`) where I couldn't in case of using boxes.

However, there are some issues that need to be fixed:

1- For the first row, how can I control both the top and bottom separations between all of the three `minipages` and the top and the bottom rules, respectively? Furthermore, why is the top separation way smaller than the bottom one?

2- In the second row, how can I make the mdframed-box be tightly placed between the horizontal rules without those top and bottom white spaces?

3- In the third row, why are the minipages skewed and not placed properly despite their total widths add to `\textwidth`, and the position option is set to be **t**op? Although when I reduce those two minipages widths a bit and playing with other minipages, they vertically align again, which doesn't make sense to me. Similarly, I need a way to control the top and bottom separations from the adjacent horizontal rules.

```
\documentclass[
addpoints,
]{exam}
\usepackage[]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum,graphbox,mdframed,array,ragged2e,booktabs,fmtcount,multicol,multirow,tabularx,cellspace,calc}
\usepackage[thinlines]{easytable}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\pagestyle{headandfoot}

\extraheadheight{7cm}

\firstpageheader%
{}%
{%
    \rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}
    \begin{minipage}[b][2cm][b]{0.33\linewidth}
        \flushleft
        left\\next left
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[b][2cm][b]{0.34\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[b][2cm][b]{0.33\linewidth}
        \flushright
        right
    \end{minipage}
    %
    \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
    %
    \begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=gray]
        \centering
        some text
    \end{mdframed}
    %
    \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
    %
    \begin{minipage}[b][2cm][c]{0.5\linewidth}
        \flushleft
        text
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[t][2cm][c]{0.5\linewidth}
        \flushright
        \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image}
    \end{minipage}
    \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
}%
{}


\begin{document}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
    \begin{questions}
        \question some question
        \question some question
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I revamped the code and replaced mdframed box with that of tcolorbox, which made it work eventually.

```
\documentclass[
addpoints,
]{exam}
\usepackage[]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum,graphbox,mdframed,array,ragged2e,booktabs,fmtcount,multicol,multirow,tabularx,cellspace,calc,tcolorbox,etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\let\NAMEquestions\numquestions
\patchcmd{\NAMEquestions}{\exam@numquestions}{{\NUMBERstringnum\exam@numquestions}}{}{}
\let\NAMEpages\numpages
\patchcmd{\NAMEpages}{\exam@lastpage}{{\NUMBERstringnum\exam@lastpage}}{}{}
\let\NAMEpoints\numpoints
\patchcmd{\NAMEpoints}{\exam@numpoints}{{\NUMBERstringnum\exam@numpoints}}{}{}
\makeatother

%\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\pagestyle{headandfoot}

\extraheadheight{7cm}

\firstpageheader%
{}%
{%
    \begin{minipage}[t][2cm][b]{0.5\textwidth}
        first\\ second\\ third
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[t][2cm][b]{0.5\textwidth}
        \flushright \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image}
    \end{minipage}%
    \vspace{2pt}
    \hrule%\vspace{5pt}
    \begin{minipage}[b][5mm][c]{0.33\textwidth}
        Semester
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[b][5mm][c]{0.34\textwidth}
        \centering Code
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[b][5mm][c]{0.33\textwidth}
        \flushright Time: 3.00 Hrs.
    \end{minipage}
    %
    \hrule
    %
    \begin{tcolorbox}[width=\textwidth,boxrule=0pt,arc=0pt,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,boxsep=5pt,colback=gray!20]
        \centering Long text
    \end{tcolorbox}
    %
    \hrule\vspace{2pt}
    %
    \begin{minipage}[b][10mm][c]{0.8\textwidth}
        This exam contains \textbf{\NAMEquestions\ questions}  in 
        \textbf{\NAMEpages\ pages}  (including this cover).\\
        The total marks are \textbf{\NAMEpoints}.
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[b][10mm][c]{0.2\textwidth}
        \flushright \thepage/\numpages
    \end{minipage}
    \hrule
}%
{}

\begin{document}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
    \begin{questions}
        \question some question
        \question some question
        \lipsum[1-8]
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]